# how to filter the list of objects and stop a service request in case of duplicate records/object by using angular 14.2.6?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an application with two angular 14 components. One is parent and the other is child component.

Parent component have an array of objects while child component add the objects by fetching from a service method.  Now I need to stop duplication and service calls if a certain code is repeated/duplicated in a list of object.

For example

```
export class MedicationPermissionModel {
    Id:number;
    ProviderSpi: string;
    canProviderCancelRx:boolean = false;
    canPharmacyCancel: boolean = false;
    endDateHasPassed: boolean = false;
    isChronicMedication: boolean  = false;
    isMedicationEprescribed:boolean = false;
    showCancelRxCheckBox:boolean = false;
}
```

this is the parent component

```
import { Component, ElementRef, Inject, OnInit, QueryList, Renderer2, ViewChildren } from  '@angular/core';
import { MatDialog, MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { ToLowerParam } from '../../../../../../../cure-client-lib/src/shared/constants/param- constants';
import { MedicationsFacesheetPopupComponent } from '../medications-facesheet-popup/medications-  facesheet-popup.component';
import { PrescriptionFacesheetService } from '../../services/prescription-facesheet.service';
import { MedicationModel } from '../../../medication/models/medication/Medication.Model';
import { TreatmentPlanStateService } from '../../../treatment-plan/services/treatmentplan-state.service';
import { TreatmentPlanFacade } from '../../../treatment-plan/services/treatmentplan- facade.service';
import { TreatmentPlan } from '../../../treatment-plan/models/treatment-plan.model';
import { OrderingComponent } from 'projects/cure-client-app/src/app/shared/enums/ordering-component.enum';
import { MedicationService } from '../../../medication/services/medication/Medication.Service';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import * as MedicationHelper from '../../../medication/utilities/medication-helper.util';
import { MdePopoverTrigger } from '@material-extended/mde';
import { NotifierService } from 'projects/cure-client-lib/src/shared/services/notifier.service';
import { LocalizationService } from 'projects/cure-client-lib/src/shared/services/localization.service';
import { MedicationPermissionModel } from '../../models/medication-permission.model';
import { PrescriptionService } from '../../../medication/services/prescription/prescription.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-medications-facesheet-tile',
  templateUrl: './medications-facesheet-tile.component.html',
})
export class MedicationsFacesheetTileComponent implements OnInit {
  medicationList: MedicationModel[] = [];
  pastMedicationList: MedicationModel[] = [];
  patientId: number;
  treatmentPlan: TreatmentPlan = {} as TreatmentPlan;
  subscription: Subscription;
  saveCallMedicationsUpdated: boolean = false;
  spiPerList : MedicationPermissionModel[] = [];
  @ViewChildren('matMedicationButtonRef', { read: ElementRef }) matButtons: QueryList<ElementRef>;
  @ViewChildren(MdePopoverTrigger) trigger: QueryList<MdePopoverTrigger>;
  showActionButtons: boolean = true;
  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private localizatonService: LocalizationService,
    private dialog: MatDialog,
    private dialogRef: MatDialogRef<MedicationsFacesheetPopupComponent>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any,
    private prescriptionService: PrescriptionFacesheetService,    
    private treatmentPlanStateService: TreatmentPlanStateService,
    private treatmentPlanService: TreatmentPlanFacade,
    private medicationService: MedicationService,
    private _renderer: Renderer2,
    private notifierService: NotifierService,
    private presService : PrescriptionService,
  ) {
    this.subscription = new Subscription();
   }    
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.subscribeForTreatmentPlan()
    this.route.queryParams.subscribe((params) => {
      const _params = ToLowerParam(params);
      if (_params['patientid'] && _params['patientid'] > 0) {
        this.patientId = Number(_params['patientid']);
      }
      else {
        return;
      }
      this.getAlreadyPrescribedMedications();
      this.getPastMedications();
    });
    this.localizatonService.setLocalizationSettingsFromStore();    
    this.subscription.add(
      this.presService.surescriptProviderMedPerListObserver.subscribe( (obj:any)  =>{
        if(obj)
        {           
         this.spiPerList.push(obj);    
          //this.presService.setSureScriptProviderMedPerList(null);      
        }
      } )
    );
  }
  private subscribeForTreatmentPlan() {
    this.treatmentPlanStateService.getTreatmentPlanObject().subscribe((treatmentPlanObj: any) =>             {
      if (treatmentPlanObj) {
        this.treatmentPlan = treatmentPlanObj;
        if(this.treatmentPlan.State === 3 ){
          this.saveCallMedicationsUpdated = true
          if(this.saveCallMedicationsUpdated){
            this.getAlreadyPrescribedMedications();
            this.getPastMedications();
          }
        }
        if(this.treatmentPlan.State >= 2){
          this.showActionButtons = false
        }
        else{
          this.showActionButtons = true
        }
      }
    }
    );
  }
  getContainerDiagnosisByCode(code: string): any {
    return this.treatmentPlan.TreatmentPlanDiagnoses.find((x) => x.Code === code);
  }
  async onSelectDiagnosis(event: any, medication: MedicationModel) {
    let selectedDiagnoses: string[] = event.selectedDiagnosisCodes
    selectedDiagnoses.forEach(element => {                  this.treatmentPlanService.addContainerComponent(OrderingComponent[OrderingComponent.Medication],     medication, this.getContainerDiagnosisByCode(element).DiagnosisClientIndex);
    });
  }
  GetTodayDate() {
    var tdate = new Date();
    var dd = tdate.getDate(); //yields day
    var MM = tdate.getMonth(); //yields month
    var yyyy = tdate.getFullYear(); //yields year
    var xxx = (MM + 1) + "/" + dd + "/" + yyyy;
    return xxx;
  }  
  private async getAlreadyPrescribedMedications() {
    let medicationList = await     this.prescriptionService.getAlreadyPrescribedMedications(this.patientId);
    if (medicationList && medicationList.Content) {
      this.medicationList = medicationList.Content;
    }
  }
  private async getPastMedications() {
    let medicationList = await this.prescriptionService.getPastMedications(this.patientId);
    if (medicationList && medicationList.Content) {
      this.pastMedicationList = medicationList.Content;
    }
  }
  onMedicationsListExpanded() {
    this.logger.info("Medications Facesheet expanded.")
    this.dialog
      .open(MedicationsFacesheetPopupComponent, {
        width: '1200px',
        data: {
          medicationList: this.medicationList,
          pastMedicationList: this.pastMedicationList,
        },
      })
      .afterClosed()
      .subscribe((result) => {
        this.logger.info('Medication Facesheet closed');
        if (result && result.event === 'submit') {
          this.dialogRef.close({ event: 'submit' });
        }
      });
  } 

  onMedicationPerMissionList(event : any){
    if(event.medicationPermission){      
      this.spiPerList.push(event.medicationPermission);    
    }
  }

  getMedicationDirections(medication : MedicationModel){
    return MedicationHelper.getMedicationDirections(medication)
  } 
}
```

and this is the child component

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, Input, OnInit, Output, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { UntypedFormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';
import { MatDialog } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { ResponseData } from 'projects/cure-client-lib/src/shared/models/response-data.model';
import { Observable, Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { MedicationModel } from '../../../medication/models/medication/Medication.Model';
import { PharmacyView } from '../../../medication/models/pharmacy/pharmacy.model';
import { Address } from '../../../medication/models/prescription/Address.model';
import { ProviderModel, Type } from '../../../medication/models/prescription/provider.model';
import { DiscontinueMedicationPopupComponent } from '../../../medication/popups/discontinue-    medication-popup/discontinue-medication-popup.component';
import { MedicationService } from '../../../medication/services/medication/Medication.Service';
import * as StringFormatter from '../../../medication/utilities/string-formatter.util'
import * as PhoneFormatter from '../../../medication/utilities/phone-formatter.util'
import { PrescriptionService } from     '../../../medication/services/prescription/prescription.service';
import { MdePopoverTrigger } from '@material-extended/mde';
import { TreatmentPlanStateService } from '../../../treatment-plan/services/treatmentplan-    state.service';
import { TreatmentPlan } from '../../../treatment-plan/models/treatment-plan.model';
import { select, Store } from '@ngrx/store';
import { StartupInfo } from 'projects/cure-client-lib/src/shared/models/startup-info.model';
import { MedicationPermissionModel } from '../../models/medication-permission.model';
import { MedicationApiGenericResponse } from '../../../medication/models/medication/medication-    api-generic-response.model';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-medication-actions',
  templateUrl: './medication-actions.component.html'
})
export class MedicationActionsComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild(MdePopoverTrigger, { static: false }) trigger: MdePopoverTrigger;
  @Input() medication : MedicationModel
  @Output() discontinuedMedication : EventEmitter<{Message : string, medication :     MedicationModel}> = new EventEmitter<{Message : string, medication : MedicationModel}>()
  @Input() spiPerList : MedicationPermissionModel[]
  @Output() medicationPerMissionList : EventEmitter<{medicationPermission :      MedicationPermissionModel}> = new EventEmitter<{medicationPermission : MedicationPermissionModel}>()
  discontinueReason: string = ''
  discontinueDescription: string = ''
  subscription : Subscription
  medicationProvider : ProviderModel
  medicationActionForm = this.fb.group({
    cancelRxSendCheck : true,
    discontinueReason : null,
    discontinueDescription : null
  })
  canProviderCancelRx: boolean = false;
  canPharmacyCancel: boolean = false;
  isMedicationEprescribed: boolean = false;
  endDateHasPassed: boolean = false;
  isChronicMedication: boolean = false;
  showCancelRxCheckBox: boolean = null;
  showActionIcons : boolean = false;
  provider : ProviderModel = new ProviderModel()
  practiceErxRights : boolean = false;
  localProvider : ProviderModel = new ProviderModel()
  medicationAlreadyInInventory: boolean = false;
  treatmentPlan: TreatmentPlan = {} as TreatmentPlan;
  emrScriptID : string = '';
  username: string;
  constructor(   
    private medicationService : MedicationService,
    private dialog : MatDialog,
    private fb : UntypedFormBuilder,   
    private prescriptionService : PrescriptionService,
    private treatmentPlanStateService: TreatmentPlanStateService
  ) {
    this.subscription = new Subscription()
    this.prescriptionService.practiceSettingsObserver.subscribe(practice => {
      if(!practice.be_Prescription){
        this.practiceErxRights = false
      }
      else{
        this.practiceErxRights = true
      }
    })
   }

  async ngOnInit() : Promise<boolean> /*:void*/ {
    //PrescriptionType: "ePrescribed"    
    try {
    this.isMedicationEprescribed = this.medication.PrescriptionType === 'ePrescribed' ? true :     false
    if(this.medication.ProviderSpi !== ''){
      
      let resultSpi:MedicationPermissionModel = this.spiPerList && this.spiPerList.length > 0 ?
      this.spiPerList.find((x) => x.ProviderSpi &&     x.ProviderSpi.indexOf(this.medication.ProviderSpi) > -1):undefined;           
      if(!resultSpi)
      {   
      
       let response: any = await this.medicationService.getProviderServiceLevelToPromise("", "",     this.medication.ProviderSpi, "", 0);
       if (response !== null && response !== undefined /*&& response !== ""*/ &&     response.MessageType !== 'Error') {
        response = JSON.parse(response);
        if (response.MessageType == "Success" && response.MessageText !== null &&     response.MessageText !== '' && response.MessageText.PrescriberResponseItems.length > 0) {
          var providers = response.MessageText.PrescriberResponseItems[0].Prescriber;
          this.provider.FirstName = providers.PersonName.FirstName
          this.provider.LastName = providers.PersonName.LastName
          let providerAddress = new Address()
          providerAddress.Address1 = providers.AddressLine1
          providerAddress.Address2 = providers.AddressLine2
          providerAddress.City = providers.City
          providerAddress.State = providers.State
          this.provider.Address = providerAddress
          this.provider.Phone = providers.Number + providers.Extension          
          if (providers !== null && providers !== '' && typeof (providers) !== 'undefined') {
            this.canProviderCancelRx = providers.bRxCancel;
         }
        }
      }

      const currentDate: Date = new Date();
      let medicationEndDate: Date = new Date(this.medication.MedicationEndDate);

      if (this.medication.MedicationEndDate != null && typeof     (this.medication.MedicationEndDate) != undefined && medicationEndDate <= currentDate) {
        this.endDateHasPassed = true;
      }

      if (!this.endDateHasPassed && this.canProviderCancelRx &&     this.medication.CanPharmacyCancel && this.isMedicationEprescribed) {
        if (this.medication.Ischronic && this.endDateHasPassed) {
          this.showCancelRxCheckBox = false;
        }
        else {
          // Open discontinue Summary screen
          this.showCancelRxCheckBox = true;
        }
      }
      else {
        // open discontinue window
        this.showCancelRxCheckBox = false;
      }

      let medPerObj: MedicationPermissionModel = {
        Id:this.medication.MedicationId,
        ProviderSpi:this.medication.ProviderSpi,
        medicationEndDate:medicationEndDate,
        canProviderCancelRx:this.canProviderCancelRx,
        canPharmacyCancel:this.medication.CanPharmacyCancel,
        endDateHasPassed:this.endDateHasPassed ,
        isChronicMedication:this.medication.Ischronic,
        isMedicationEprescribed:this.isMedicationEprescribed,
        showCancelRxCheckBox:this.showCancelRxCheckBox
      };       
      this.prescriptionService.setSSProvMedPerList(medPerObj);  
      
    }
    else if(resultSpi)
      {
        this.canProviderCancelRx = resultSpi.canProviderCancelRx;
        this.canPharmacyCancel = resultSpi.canPharmacyCancel;
        this.isChronicMedication = resultSpi.isChronicMedication;
        this.endDateHasPassed = resultSpi.endDateHasPassed;
        this.medication.Ischronic = resultSpi.isChronicMedication;
        this.showCancelRxCheckBox = resultSpi.showCancelRxCheckBox;
      } 
    }
    else{
      this.showCancelRxCheckBox = false;
    }
    this.checkMedicationOnHover();
    this.loadStartupInfoFromStore();
    return Promise.resolve(true);
  } catch (error) {
    return Promise.resolve(false);
  }

  }


  GetTodayDate() {
    var tdate = new Date();
    var dd = tdate.getDate(); //yields day
    var MM = tdate.getMonth(); //yields month
    var yyyy = tdate.getFullYear(); //yields year
    var xxx = (MM + 1) + "/" + dd + "/" + yyyy;
    return xxx;
  }
  onDiscontinueReasonUpdated(event) {
    this.discontinueReason = event.reason;
    this.discontinueDescription = event.description;
  } 

}
```

and this is the html file for parent component

```
<div class="">
  <div class="card card-default">
    <div class="card-title">
      <h4 class="d-flex align-items-center header-title">
      <img src="assets/images/medications.svg" width="20" class="facesheet-svg mr-2" alt="" />
        <span class="facesheet-title" [ngClass]="{
          'disabled-icon':
            (this.medicationList == null &&
              this.pastMedicationList == null) ||
            (this.medicationList == [] && this.pastMedicationList == [])
          }" (click)="onMedicationsListExpanded()">
              <span>Medications&nbsp;</span>
          <span class="icon icon-expand fz-14"></span>
        </span>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body pt-0">
    <div *ngIf="this.medicationList == null || this.medicationList?.length == 0"
        class="no-record-found">
        <div class="">
          <h5>No record found</h5>
        </div>
      </div>
    <ul *ngIf="this.medicationList != null && this.medicationList?.length != 0"
      class="header-listing medications-listing">
      <li *ngFor="let medication of this.medicationList; let i = index">
        <span mat-raised-button color="primary"
        [id]="index"
        #matMedicationButtonRef
        [mdePopoverTriggerFor]="appPopover"
        mdePopoverTriggerOn="hover"
        [mdePopoverEnterDelay]="500"
        (mouseleave)="matBtnOnLeave(popoverTrigger, index)"
        [mdePopoverTriggerFor]="appPopover"
        #popoverTrigger="mdePopoverTrigger"
    >
            {{ medication.MedicationName }}
          </span>

          <mde-popover
            #appPopover="mdePopover"
            [mdePopoverOverlapTrigger]="false"
          >
            <mat-card class="mde-popover-detailed" style="max-width: 400px">
              <mat-card-content>
                <h4 class="popover-title">{{ medication.MedicationName }}</h4>
                <div class="popover-body px-0 pb-0">
                  <div class="row medication-details">
                    <div class="col-sm-4" style="align-self: baseline;">
                        <h5 class="mb-0">Direction</h5>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-8 pl-0">
                        <span>{{ getMedicationDirections(medication) }}</span>
                    </div>
                  </div>                                
              </div>
            </mat-card-content>
          </mat-card>
        </mde-popover>
        <app-medication-actions [ngClass]="this.showActionButtons ? '':'d-none'"     [medication]="medication"  [spiPerList]="this.spiPerList"     (medicationPerMissionList)="this.onMedicationPerMissionList($event)" 
        (discontinuedMedication)="this.onDiscontinueMedication($event)"></app-medication-    actions>
      </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem is with async     `ngOnInit() : Promise<boolean>` in child component.
There are four medication child components and I have added this duplication logic
let resultSpi:MedicationPermissionModel = this.spiPerList && this.spiPerList.length > 0 ?
this.spiPerList.find((x) => x.ProviderSpi &&     x.ProviderSpi.indexOf(this.medication.ProviderSpi) > -1):undefined;
if(!resultSpi) `
before calling to the     getProviderServiceLevelToPromise function.  I don't want to call it fours times if spiPerList already have a Providerspi code. But rather than checking the duplicate logic for each medicine or child component , system stayed at this line

```
this.prescriptionService.setSureScriptProviderMedPerList(medPerObj);   `
```

and never goes up to the flow.
this are the package.json

```
{
  "name": "",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "build:elements": "ng build patientbanner --configuration production --output-hashing none     && node concatenate.js"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^14.2.6",
    "@angular/cdk": "^14.2.5",
    "@angular/common": "^14.2.6",
    "@angular/compiler": "^14.2.6",
    "@angular/core": "^14.2.6",
    "@angular/elements": "^14.2.6",
    "@angular/forms": "^14.2.6",
    "@angular/material": "^14.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^14.2.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^14.2.6",
    "@angular/router": "^14.2.6",
    "@angular/service-worker": "^14.2.6",
    "@dipaktelangre/age-calculator": "^1.0.7",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^6.0.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.3.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.0.0",
    "@kolkov/angular-editor": "^1.2.0",
    "@material-extended/mde": "^3.0.3",
    "@microsoft/signalr": "^6.0.9",
    "@ncstate/sat-popover": "^8.0.1",
    "@ngrx/component-store": "^12.5.1",
    "@ngrx/effects": "^12.5.1",
    "@ngrx/store": "^12.5.1",
    "@ngrx/store-devtools": "^12.5.1",
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.10.2",
    "@types/mixpanel": "^2.14.3",
    "@types/mixpanel-browser": "^2.35.7",
    "angular-file": "^3.6.0",
    "angular-formio": "^4.11.5",
    "angular-highcharts": "^12.0.0",
    "angular-split": "^14.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "^3.4.1",
    "browser-image-compression": "^2.0.0",
    "ckeditor4-angular": "^3.1.1",
    "concat": "^1.0.3",
    "dhtmlx-scheduler": "^5.3.8",
    "dragula": "^3.7.3",
    "fs-extra": "^10.1.0",
    "highcharts": "^9.2.2",
    "highcharts-angular": "^2.10.0",
    "lodash-es": "^4.17.21",
    "mixpanel-browser": "^2.41.0",
    "ng2-dragula": "^2.1.1",
    "ng2-tooltip-directive": "^2.10.3",
    "ngx-image-cropper": "^6.3.2",
    "ngx-infinite-scroll": "^10.0.1",
    "ngx-logger": "^4.2.2",
    "ngx-mat-select-search": "^4.0.2",
    "ngx-material-timepicker": "^5.5.3",
    "ngx-owl-carousel-o": "^6.0.0",
    "ngx-popperjs": "^12.2.1",
    "ngx-print": "^1.2.1",
    "ngx-toastr": "^14.3.0",
    "ngx-webcam": "^0.4.1",
    "recordrtc": "^5.6.2",
    "rxjs": "^6.6.7",
    "swiper": "^8.4.2",
    "tslib": "^2.2.0",
    "vanilla-text-mask": "^5.1.1",
    "wavesurfer.js": "^6.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^14.2.6",
    "@angular-eslint/builder": "12.1.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "12.1.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "12.1.0",
    "@angular-eslint/schematics": "^12.6.0",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "12.1.0",
    "@angular/cli": "^14.2.6",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^14.2.6",
    "@types/dhtmlxscheduler": "^4.3.39",
    "@types/jasmine": "^3.6.11",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.5.10",
    "@types/node": "^12.20.55",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "4.23.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "4.23.0",
    "angular-file": "^3.6.0",
    "eslint": "^7.26.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.22.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsdoc": "30.7.6",
    "eslint-plugin-prefer-arrow": "1.2.2",
    "husky": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.2",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.6.0",
    "ng-packagr": "^14.2.1",
    "prettier": "^2.3.1",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint-config-prettier": "^1.18.0",
    "typescript": "~4.6.4"
  }
}
```

Now control always stay at                   `this.prescriptionService.setSureScriptProviderMedPerList(medPerObj);`

Guide me. thank you!

Expected behaviour:

I want to stop calling this function     `this.medicationService.getProviderServiceLevelToPromise("", "", this.medication.ProviderSpi, "", 0);` unless a unique `this.medication.ProviderSpi` exists.